# Facebook SDK Error on Installing Cocoapods Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, sdk

After installing Facebook SDK via Cocoapods in my Objective-C app, hundreds of errors were appearing.

Things like this:

```
Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Foundation._ErrorCodeProtocol
Undefined symbol: method descriptor for Foundation._BridgedStoredNSError.init(_nsError: __C.NSError) -> A
Undefined symbol: associated type descriptor for Foundation._BridgedStoredNSError.Code
Undefined symbol: base conformance descriptor for Foundation._BridgedStoredNSError: Swift.Hashable

[...]
```

I lost hours and hours trying to figure out why this errors occurred, installed, re-installed and nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

So, i found the solution for this errors on another problem completely different from mine.
On this [github post](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/issues/1059#issuecomment-493925940) the guy said to follow this steps, and i did:

1 - Open ios/YourAppName.xcodeproj in Xcode

2 - Right-click on Your App Name in the Project Navigator on the left, and click New File…

3 - Create a single empty Swift file to the project (make sure that Your App Name target is selected when adding)

4 - when Xcode asks, press Create Bridging Header and do not remove Swift file then. re-run your build.
This should fix the problem

And it worked like a charm.

If you have the same problem, i hope help you guys!

Comment: I didnt tested without creating bridging headers, but, it works with it, so, thats ok.

Comment: In my case, this happened after I added Facebook Login to a React Native app. This answer helped. I didn't have to create a bridging and tested with no issues. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Great Answer man. I was just shocked when I seen 100 errors while compilation.